# forecasting daily data using tbats and ets

Tags: r, dataset, time-series, prediction, forecasting

i have this data so the column contain the number of products ordered that say .  each line represents a daily order the first order starts 01/01/2012 and the last order was 31/12/2012 . i want to predict the next orders for the whole next year so i applied tbats and ets and i got basically the same results but i think it's not correct here's what i've got using tbats for example that doesn't look like the intial orders plotted.i applied also arima but i've got nothing too.Sorry for bad english[image]

and here's my data :
[data](https://1fichier.com/?0ar4ztet2o)

here's what i did to get the tbats forecast for example:

```
  sensor <- ts(data2,frequency=365, start=c(1,1))
  fit <- tbats(sensor)
  fc <- forecast(fit)
  plot(fc)
```

Comment: How far out are you predicting at a time? just one day? is the data summed by day? do you have weekly seasonality? do you have other covariates that you'd like to include?

Comment: no othe covariates to include and yes the data is summed by day and let's say i want to predict the next year

Comment: you're not going to be able to predict a whole year at once with your data unless you do a nieve prediction and just say it's the same as the last year. You could predict the next week's sales though

Comment: how's that please i need some help

Comment: i think i should use roston but how ?